# If for every positive number $\varepsilon$ there exists a positive number $\delta$, why not the other way back?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

**Definition.**

*Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$. **If for every positive number $\varepsilon$, however small it may be, there exists a number $\delta$** such that whenever 0 $<$ |x - a| $<$ $\delta$ we have |f(x) - l| $<$ $\varepsilon$, then we say $f(x)$ tends to the limit $l$ as 'x tends to a' and write*

$\lim_{x \to a}$ $f(x)$ = $l$

**Proposed definition**.

*Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$. **If for every positive number $\delta$, however small it may be, there exists a number $\varepsilon$** such that whenever 0 $<$ |x - a| $<$ $\delta$ we have |f(x) - l| $<$ $\varepsilon$, then we say $f(x)$ tends to the limit $l$ as 'x tends to a' and write*

$\lim_{x \to a}$ $f(x)$ = $l$

**Question:** How would the proposed definition affect the way we evaluate a limit?

Comment: Think of $\epsilon$ as your vertical window, $\delta$ your horizontal wriggle-room. The order of the definition is key: adjusting the vertical callipers, we can always widen the horizontal callipers sufficiently to make the statement true. This is a big-picture overview, and I'll leave it for another to make the counterexample.

Comment: We would have a different definition if we reversed the implication.

Comment: Please carefully write down your proposed new definition in the body of your question so that we know exactly what you mean by "What would happen if δ implied ε?" which is very incomplete.

Comment: @Somos Is it clear now?

Comment: Under your proposed definition, if $f(x)$ is bounded near $a$, then it would have all real numbers as limits at $a$. So the definition would only identify “bounded near $a$”, and would limits would not have a specific value, but either no value or all values.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Why is $f(x)$ bounded near $a$?

Comment: @Nameless: If $f(x)$ is not bounded near $a$, then for every $M\gt 0$ and every $\delta\gt 0$ there exists $x$, $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta$ such that $|f(x)|\gt M$. Then for any real number $L$, any $\delta\gt 0$, and every $\epsilon\gt 0$ we can find a value of $x$ that satisfies $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta$ but $|f(x)$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $L$; for instance, by picking $M$ to be $|L|+2\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,&\text{if } x>0, \\ 0,&\text{if } x\le0.\end{cases}
$$
This function is clearly not continuous at $x=0$; from the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, we can see this by choosing $\varepsilon=\frac12$, and noting that there does not exist $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(0)|<\frac12$ for all $|x|<\delta$.

However, this function does satisfy a hypothetical "$\delta$-$\varepsilon$ definition": for any $\delta>0$, we can choose $\varepsilon=2$, and it is definitely true that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$. (Indeed, any bounded function would satisfy this "$\delta$-$\varepsilon$ definition" for example, and there are plenty of bounded functions that are not continuous.)

(I hope this answers the question you mean to ask. The statement "$\varepsilon$ implies $\delta$" doesn't have a precise meaning when $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ are numbers, and I'd encourage you while learning the subject to make sure that you use the mathematical notation in precise ways—doing otherwise allows misconceptions to become more entrenched.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could please provide an example in which my "hypothetical" definition does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You proposed definition

> *Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$. **If for every positive number $\delta$, however small it may be, there exists a number $\varepsilon$** such that whenever 0 $<$ |x - a| $<$ $\delta$ we have |f(x) - l| $<$ $\varepsilon$, then we say $f(x)$ tends to the limit $l$ as 'x tends to a' and write*
> $\lim_{x \to a}$ $f(x)$ = $l$

is a valid definition, but not for a limit. In fact, the bolded phrase is misleading
because if it is true for a single $\,\delta>0\,$ then it implies it is true for all smaller $\,\delta>0.\,$ Thus, it would be better phrased with **small** replaced with
**large**. What the definition defines is that the function $\,f(x)\,$ is bounded in
any deleted neighborhood of the real $\,a\,$ and furthermore, the value of the
real $\,l\,$ does not matter since we can always choose $\,\varepsilon\,$ big enough
so that the interval $\,(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)\,$ contains the interval
$\,[\liminf(f(x)),\limsup(f(x))]\,$ of the range of $\,f(x)\,$ where $\,x\,$ is restricted to $\, 0 < |x - a| < \delta.\,$ In fact, the real $\,a\,$ does not
matter for the same reason.

Also, there is now no need to restrict to a **deleted** neighborhood. The
restriction should be to $\, |x - a| < \delta\,$ instead because the value
$\,f(a)\,$ does not cause any problems since it only requires that the bounds
include it. Its value does not change the boundedness of the function. Note
that in the actual definition of continuity, you forgot to explictly state that **both** $\,a\,$ and $\,l\,$ are given reals. An improved version of your definition for a **locally** bounded function with the role of $\,a\,$ and $\,l\,$ made explicit is:

---

Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x$. **If for every real $\,a\,$ and positive
real $\delta$, however large it may be, there exists reals  $\varepsilon$**
and $\,l\,$  such that
whenever $|x - a| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - l| < \varepsilon,\,$ then we
say that $\,f(x)\,$ is a locally bounded function.

---

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for that helpful comment! I will fix it.